# The minimum value $\frac{a_1+...+a_n}{b_1+...+b_n}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a_1, a_2,..., a_n, b_1, b_2,..., b_n$ positve numbers s.t. $\frac{a_1}{b_1}\leq \frac{a_2}{b_2}\leq...\leq \frac{a_n}{b_n}$. Find the minimum for the expression $$\frac{a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n}{b_1x_1+...+b_nx_n}$$, where $ 0<x_1 \leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n$.

I think that the minimum is $\frac{a_1+...+a_n}{b_1+...+b_n}$.

For n=2 this is equivalent with $\frac{a_1+a_2}{b_1+b_2}\leq \frac{a_1x_1+a_2x_2}{b_1x_1+b_2x_2}$, for every $0< x_1\leq x_2$. This is equivalent with $(a_2b_1-a_1b_2)(x_1-x_2)\leq 0$ which is true because $a_2b_1-a_1b_2\geq 0$ and $x_1-x_2\leq 0$. But now I am stuck because I don't know to construct an inductive argument.

Comment: You have already asked this question today.

Comment: @Aig I tried those ideas but I don't know to finish.

Comment: It’s not the valid reason to spam the same question though.

Comment: Great that you did the $n=2$ case. Can you try the $n =3$ case? Not asking you to jump off and do the induction, but just brute force the $n=3$ to see if there potentially is a pattern we could induct on. If there isn't, then I wouldn't try induction. If there is, maybe we could get it more directly.

Comment: Separately, Martin R indicated that it is essentially another question. Following that train of thought, 1/ Do you understand the other question? 2/ How could you modify yours to be the other question?